# Several Questions about Moments

Tags: probability-theory

1. [This document](https://www2.cirano.qc.ca/~dufourj/Web_Site/ResE/Dufour_2008_C_TS_Moments.pdf) says in page 1 at Subsection 1.2 that
   \begin{equation}
   \text{$\mathrm{E}[X]$ exists and is finite}\Leftrightarrow\mathrm{E}[|X|]<\infty
   \end{equation}
   and I do not know what is the difference between "$\mathrm{E}[|X|]$ is finite" and "$\mathrm{E}[|X|]<\infty$" (for me it seems it prevents the possibility of $-\infty$ though). Can I restate the former as "$\exists\mathrm{E}[X]\text{ and }-\infty<\mathrm{E}[X]<\infty$" instead, or can I restate the latter as "$\mathrm{E}[|X|]\text{ is positive and finite}$" instead?
2. It seems existence and finiteness of moments are different. What is the example of "$\mathrm{E}[X]\text{ exists but infinite}$" then?
3. Can I say
   \begin{equation}
   -\infty<\mathrm{E}[X]<\infty\Leftrightarrow\mathrm{E}[|X|]<\infty
   \end{equation}
   then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper formal framework to discuss expected values is the theory of (Lebesgue) integration over abstract measure spaces. In the Lebesgue theory, there are two distinct concepts of the integral: the unsigned integral and the signed integral. The unsigned integral is defined for all positive random variables $Y$ and is defined to be

$$
\Bbb E[Y] := \int_\Omega Y(\omega) \, d\Bbb P(\omega)=\sup_{\stackrel{0\le \phi\le Y}{\phi = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \Bbb 1_{E_n} \text{ simple}}} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \Bbb P(E_n).
$$

For a general signed random variable $X$, if $\Bbb E[|X|] < +\infty$, in the sense above, we then define $X^+ = \max(X,0)$ and $X^- = \max(-X,0)$. In which case $X^\pm$ are positive random variables and $X = X^+ - X^- $ and we define the signed integral as

$$
\Bbb E[X] := \Bbb E[X^+] - \Bbb E[X^-]. \tag{1}
$$

*Note that if $\Bbb E[|X|] = +\infty$, $\Bbb E[X]$ is not even defined.* For if $\Bbb E[|X|] = +\infty$, then it may be the case that $\Bbb E[X^+] = \Bbb E[X^-] = +\infty$ in which case (1) makes no sense. Thus, to all of your point, if $\Bbb E[|X|] = +\infty$ (the same as saying $\Bbb E[|X|]$ is infinite), then $\Bbb E[X]$ is not well-defined in general which makes even writing $\Bbb E[X]$ down to be non-sensical.

Comment: You certainly mean: Note that if $\mathbb{E}[|X|] = +\infty$, ...

Comment: @S.M.Roch Yes of course. Fixed

Comment: Thanks. One more quick question. Why must it be "$\mathrm{E}[X]$ exists and is finite?" It seems it is just OK by saying that "$\mathrm{E}[X]$ is finite," which already implies the existence then.

Comment: @JunyongKim This is an interesting philosophical question. In real analysis, for example, we often write down $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ before we know whether or not this series actually converges. The question of how to refer to an object like an expected value or infinite sum before you know it exists is somewhat debatable. I think the author says $E[X]$ exists and is finite to make it crystal clear to the reader that (a) the existence of $E[X]$ is not a foregone conclusion (it is possible for $E[X]$ not to exist) and (b) that it does indeed exist.

Comment: Still weird since "$\mathrm{E}[X]$ does not exist but is finite" is impossible. My apology but one more. It seems $\mathrm{E}[|X|]=\infty$ implies either $\mathrm{E}\left[X^+\right]=\infty$ or $\mathrm{E}\left[X^-\right]=\infty$ or $\mathrm{E}\left[X^+\right]=\mathrm{E}\left[X^-\right]=\infty$. Then can I say "$\mathrm{E}[|X|]\in\mathbb{R}$ implies $\mathrm{E}[X],\mathrm{E}\left[X^+\right],\mathrm{E}\left[X^-\right]\in\mathbb{R}$?"

Comment: @JunyongKim Yes since $E[|X|] = E[X^+] + E[X^-]$ so if $E[|X|] < \infty$, then $ E[X^+],  E[X^-],  E[X] = E[X^+]-E[X^-] < E[|X|] < \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Care must be taken to distinguish between $E[X]$ and $E[|X|]$.

As stated in (1.1), either $E[|X|]$ is a non-negative real number or $E[|X|]=\infty$.

The phrase "$E[|X|]<\infty$" excludes the latter possibility.

As for an example, note that $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac 1 {t^2} \ \mathrm dt = 1$ while $\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac {t} {t^2} \ \mathrm dt = \infty$.

Your paraphrasing at the end is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the expactation value is

$$E[X] = \int_{\Omega} X dP$$

where $(\Omega, B, P)$ is your probability space.

Now $E[X]$ exists means, that the integral is well defined. Note that the integral is typical defined as the integral over the positive part minus the integral over the negative part, but $\infty - \infty$ is not allowed.

If $E[X]$ exists, then $E[X] < \infty$ means just $E[X] \neq +\infty$.

$E[|X|]$ always exists, since |X| is never negative, so the integral over the negative part is 0.

Answer (score 0):

No; "not exists" and "not finite" are not the same thing.

It has to do with evaluation for limits of series.   If a series converges then the limit will either be *finite* or *infinite*, though either way the limit does exist.   However, if the series is non-convergent, then we say that the limit *does not exist*.

These definitions are inherited by expectations, which are evaluated as either series or integrals (which also inherit these definition).

The expectation of a certainly non-negative random variable will always exist, as either some finite positive value, or having a positive infinite limit.  (Likewise a certainly non-positive random variable's expectation will exist.)

However, if a random variable may realise negative or positive values , then its expectation may be finite, infinite, *or* not exist.

---

We toss a coin until it turns up tails, accumulating payout, $X$, on each head and betting that if the payout is positive I pay you, else you pay me (the absolute value).

- The initial payout is two dollars.
- For each head that shows before the first tail, we multiply the payout by $-2$.

  - So if $N$ counts the tosses before the first tail, then $X=(-1)^N(2)^{N+1}\mathbf 1_{N\geq 0}$, and of course $$\mathsf P\left(X{=}(-1)^n(-2)^{n+1}\right)~=~\mathsf P(N{=}n)~=~2^{-(n+1)}\mathbf 1_{n\geq 0}$$

Now $\mathsf E(\lvert X\rvert)~=~\sum_{n=0}^\infty 1$. This series clearly converges towards the infinite.   So although the limit is non-finite, we usually say that "it exists".

But $\mathsf E(X) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}$.   This series does not converge.   The partial sum alternates between $1$ and $0$, so we cannot say the series is infinite.   However, it certainly is not finite either.   This is what we mean by "it does not exist".